# how can I print UID, GID for specific user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to print the GID and UID for specific user to be printed  for examples the user is student , I want GID and UID to be printed only for them using terminal linux

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Also SO is not a code-writing service. You show us what you did, and where you are having problems!

Comment: id username. This is not a code question. I believe this isn't even a question

Comment: Use `getent passwd $username` and then parse the output. uid is column 3; gid is column 4

Comment: ps -eo  "%c %p %P %U" | grep student , this command does not print UID ,GID how can I print GID and UID with this command

Answer (score 1):

What they say is true, but in the interest of helping you out: check out the **id** command.

Answer (score 0):

cat /etc/passwd | grep username | cut -d: -f3 -f4